# MS Access datasheet view does not display nulls?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way in MS Access (2007) to display null values (opposed to empty strings) from the datasheet view.

Progmatically SQL is inserting hard coded null values without error and the column property "Allow Zero Length" is set to No, so I thought a null value would be inserted  but when viewing the table within MS Access it appears as an empty string.

Is a null being inserted?

Does MS Access not display 'null' as a value or keyword??

Is there a setting I need to change to view nulls?

This is leading to confusion and is becoming a real pain!

Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Access, it is not possible to tell by looking at a table or datasheet whether you have a zero length string or a null. If you inserted nulls, that is what you have got, it can be quite difficult to insert zero length strings into recent versions of Access. You can use Nz in a query to display a value where null is found, but you cannot edit the result.

Comment: Seems mad but I suppose it's not exactly and enterprise db

Comment: Why would you want to display a value for Nulls? This is a presentation-level issue, and the database engine itself should not do anything at all in this regard. What database are you accustomed to that behaves any differently?

Comment: The question is asking about the datasheet view (i.e. the UI not the engine), so it seems reasonable to want to distinguish nulls from empty strings visually and to be able to enter nulls and empty strings as distinct values. Other database UIs do exactly this (e.g. SQL Server Management Server), but unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Access.